# Anchors Tag - retire it in favor of more specific alternatives

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, tag-merge-request

The [anchors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anchors) tag is mostly rock-climbing questions, but with a few boating and snow anchor questions mixed in.  There's also the [setting-up-an-anchor](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setting-up-an-anchor) tag that's not used much.

I'd suggest retiring the `anchors` tag since it's ambiguous and using more specific tags instead, such as `climbing-anchors`, `boat-anchors`, `snow-anchors`, etc.  The `setting-up-an-anchor` questions could be migrated to `climbing-anchors`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would do much to clear potential tag confusion on these items.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I've created the [climbing-anchors] tag with a summary and submitted a number of edits for review to migrate questions to it

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this is unwanted tag fragmentation. The reason why umbrella tags are a good thing (especially as we are talking about very few questions here) are described in this answer:
https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/a/800/3602

E.g. some of these questions are not specific to climbing, but mountaineering in general. The link to the specific activity is already given by tagging something with [anchor](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anchor) and [climbing](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climbing) or [boats](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boats)...

So if you feel the need to retag with specific tag, please leave the general tag [anchor](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anchor) in place as well.

Comment: I can see that, however could you point me to a basic resource showing how a mountaineering anchor differs?  A quick google search turned up a small number of references to what I'd consider snow or climbing anchors but nothing distinct--in which case should the umbrella tag be [tag:mountaineering] instead of [tag:anchors]?

Comment: I just mean that building an anchor with e.g. pitons applies not only to climbing which is a subset of mountaineering. So "climbing-anchors" is too narrow, while just "anchors" can be combined with any other tag to fit exactly into the right scope.

Comment: *climbing which is a subset of mountaineering* Huh? I'd put it the other way around. If you're mountaineering, then you're climbing something. Mountaineering is a subset of climbing. Rock climbing is also a subset of climbing.